# US State Boundary Shapefiles

Tags: data-request, usa

Anybody know where I can download shapefiles of individual US state outlines? Something in the 1:100k range

I found this, but albert's is better (the census data requires processing)

https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_cousub.html

Comment: Did you download the census shapefiles?  It certainly looks like they should be the states.  https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-cart-boundary.html

Comment: I did, but the states are all grouped together.  I need this so I can clip data to state boundaries, so the census data isn't really useful

Comment: you're using qgis - use it to clip out each state individually. open the data, under layer, go to attribute table. census data should be grouped by each state. so simple deletion. repeat 49x.

Comment: I opened the attribute table, and deleting doesn't seem to be an option, for whatever reason (the button is grayed out and not clickable). I'd rather find data that doesn't need any processing though (if possible); this is how a 5 minute download turns into a 5 day project...

Comment: All of the edit type features aren't usable on the census map; I think it's read only

Comment: @albert Thank you for validating my original response would have worked. I should have left it rather than creating a second one. Just deleted the second one.

Comment: you have to click the edit button. looks like a pencil, all the way to the left. that allows editing; then click the row(s) you want to edit, and in this case, then click delete. it works for me with this dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This dataset specifically has the state outlines broken out individually [https://github.com/michalsen/states_geojson/](https://github.com/michalsen/states_geojson/tree/master/states), and here's another flavor with [zip codes](https://github.com/OpenDataDE/State-zip-code-GeoJSON)